# Laravel Chat Message. Saving Image send in chat?

Tags: php, database, image, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.3 and developing an app for IOS developer. I have been working on a user-user chat. I have already designed the database and backend logic in laravel. Everything is working fine for now.

Now my client wants to send images and videos in chat as well. A chat/Messaging system like Facebook. I am using phpmyadmin (MySql). Current structure:

[image]

**Question 1** Can anyone help me understand that Is it a good approach to
save the image in database for chat purpose (keeping in mind that I am using phpmyadmin) or have to upload it in folder and save the link instead? If I have to save the path to image, then what will my database structure look like?

**Question 2** Is there any chat tutorial availabe that save the **image in database** as well? Or gives the idea how to do that?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store image in some folger eg. `public_path("uploads/")` in laravel

create new image_path field in your existing table and store the image name in that field, name the image like this timestamp + random

eg. `date("YmdHis").str_random(6).'.jpg'`

This is the mostly used way for storing images in db..